# Can a frontend (in Angular) handle multiple backends?

Tags: python, c#, angular, docker, iis

My company offers a financial product (on-prem) built in C#, SQL Server (back end) and Angular (front end) with Microsoft IIS as web server. The back end is mostly done in the database layer, using a bunch of dynamic SQL/stored procedures, where the C# part mostly handles communication with the front end.

Now we want to introduce a machine learning product into the same front end. However, the issue is that the data science team codes in Python. Instead of having C# execute Python scripts, we've talked about making a Python micro service. This would allow the data science team to work independently.

The service would be a ML app that's build into a Python web framework (such as Django, FastAPI, etc) and then containerized using Docker. The app will also handle authentication. Communication to and from the app is through RESTful API's and a DB connection to a on-prem database. We assume that the primary product and the microservice is running on the same server ("next" to each other).

We want the front end to communicate with both back ends (the primary product and the microservice). Can this be done? Or more importantly, should this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Angular is a front-end which is a client so it is **not care** about the language of REST APIs so it can deal with different APIs on different hosts with different languages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done as i can understand your backends are REST services as long as they are REST nothing is gonna change also Angular has good HttpClient wrappers which will handle all the REST call easily and nicely